# Node-Based pathfinding vs A* and others

Tags: path-finding

Whats the difference between node-based pathfinding algorithm and the A* among others?

A friend just told me about node-based, but I cannot find much tutorial or information on it.

Comment: Would your friend be talking about [Dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm)? It's such a good node-based pathfinding algorithm that _internet routing runs on it_.

Comment: @Axidos: Dijkstra's is uninformed A*; if you can come up with _any_ heuristic, A* is better.

Comment: @Joe Wreschnig: So it is! I didn't realise that - thanks for giving me a reason to investigate!

Comment: Dijkstra is basically A* without heuristic. Using Dijkstra is really useful if you want to find the nearest item of type X. Eg. your Bot is looking for the nearest ammo-crate, then Dijkstra's will find you the nearest one.

Comment: @bummzack: Not really a good example - A* is still better if you have any admissible estimate of where the nearest ammo-crate is, usually (and trivially) Euclidean distance. And if you don't want your AI to be omniscient and actually have to explore, depth-first searches will probably be better (or at least make AIs look more intentioned) than breadth-first searches (including Dijkstra).

Comment: @Joe not really, since Eucledian distance can be totally misleading (eg. item is behind a large wall) and you're not looking for **one** goal (where A* shines), but for the nearest item out of *N* candidates. I still think in this case a breadth first search like Dijkstras is a good approach.

Comment: @bummzack: I think you're not understanding A*. If it's behind a wall, A* means you consider cells approaching that wall first, not that you don't find the nearest one eventually. At worst, the heuristic function biases you towards the dead-end during the start of your search, but it will give up that branch as soon as it starts moving away from the ammo because of the wall, and you are still guaranteed the nearest ammo box in the end.

Comment: @bummzack: While you can construct degenerate cases where h(x)=0 finds the ammo before h(x)=dist(x), in the average real world case the difference is either minimal (some short discarded branches) or _drastically_ in favor of A*, as with an open area.

Comment: @Joe: So you're saying that you would change the goal in A* during search (if it turns out that the create you were steering to is actually further away than another one)? I think that would result in a new search for every crate then?

Comment: bummzack: I'm proposing h(x) = min(map(x.dist, ammo_crates)). I'm not changing the goal at any point during running the algorithm - I'm defining the goal to be the nearest ammo crate, rather than specifically the Euclidean-nearest crate. The whole point of A* is that once g(x) > g(y) + h(y), it's going to start exploring down y no matter how small h(x) is.

Comment: @Joe Wreschnig: Ok I think I understand now. So your heuristic is basically evaluating the closest crate (Eucledian-nearest) in each iteration of the search algorithm? So the search might converge to a create but then change direction once onother crate is closer than the previous one? Not sure if that would always find the closest crate though? Example: http://imgur.com/xPxWf in that scenario the player (red) would search left, then down and most likely find the crate (green) at the bottom, whereas the nearest would have been on the right.

Comment: @Joe Wreschnig: I was wrong with my assumption. A* will indeed be superior to Djikstras in this case. Sorry for the lengthy comment-discussion :)

Comment: Since when A* does not use nodes? A* is graph search algorithm, graph is defined by nodes and edges.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My AI is rusty, but it sounds like your friend is describing a common approach to defining the environment for the pathfinding: explicitly or algorithmically define a set of discrete nodes that agents can travel between in a network.  Once you've got that node graph, you can run any algorithm you want on it, including A*.

A* can be run on a grid (which is really just a very regularly-spaced set of nodes) or a terrain mesh, too.  Making a node graph is just a way to simplify a complex pathfinding situation by defining possible paths through an area.

Of course, there may be a definition of "node-based pathfinding" with which I am unfamiliar.

Answer (score 6):

A* *is* node-based. In fact, the only difference between A* and depth-first, breadth-first, uniform cost and every other graph search algorithm is how they determine the next node to visit. Using a stack, queue, priority queue based on cost from start, and a priority queue based on cost from start plus estimated cost to goal yields DFS, BFS, uniform cost and A* respectively.

Graph search algorithms, especially A*, sound all mysterious until you grok what I said above - then they all become obvious. I plan to write a set of articles for my blog exploring this topic in depth.

Answer (score 1):

Dijkstra's algorithm gives the correct answer on any grid of nodes, and exaustively finds the best route. If you have a small number of pre-populated nodes on your map (e.g. you placed them in your editor) then there are probably sufficiently few that it works fine.

On the other hand A* uses a "distance function" (typically manhattan distance or something) to optimise Dijkstra's algorithm for the special case where you have a very large number of evenly spaced nodes, e.g. a grid - which is the normal case.

The A* algorithm can find the best route in a grid with some caveats regarding weights. For example, if you place a few teleporters on an otherwise grid-like map, A* can no longer work, as its "Distance funcion" doesn't give the right result, taking into account the teleporters.

But Dijkstra isn't efficient** on a big open grid either, because the number of nodes you have to consider gets big quickly. Dijkstra's algorithm is like a flood-fill - it always touches all reachable nodes. A* does not.

I'm not sure if this answers your question but I hope it helps.

** For a given defintions of "efficient" and "big".

Comment: That you choose a bad heuristic for your data doesn't make A* "not work" - it still does what it mathematically claims to. You just need to pick an admissible heuristic - like the minimum of the distance to the goal *or* the nearest teleporter - and it'll find the optimal path at least as fast as Dijkstra's.